# Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting this error:

> "Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference"

On IE version 11. Please help.

```
            document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

    var type = document.appendEqprop[5].value.toUpperCase();
    var valueS = document.appendEqprop[6].value.toUpperCase();
    var canSubmit = validateEntry(type,valueS);

   if (canSubmit)
    {
        document.appendEqprop[11].disabled = false;
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }

     if (!canSubmit || valueS.length == 0)
        {
        document.appendEqprop[11].disabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: You're using two different syntaxes to call `.getElementById()`. One of them is correct (`( )`), the other is not.

Comment: Also, IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy still having the same error with edited version.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your markup?

Comment: Thanks @SLaks still having the same error with edited version.

Comment: What is the definition of `document.appendEqprop`?